# Laravel nova filter cards on dashboard

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I need to create a dashboard that has 2 cards. 1 card displays the total registered users and another 1 displays total verified users. There's also a date filter for user column created_at. What's the correct way to do this because there's no filter method found on a custom nova dashboard.

```
public function filters(Request $request)
{
  return [];
}
```

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: I'm also looking for something like this. This looks interesting: https://github.com/nemrutco/nova-global-filter. I'll post an answer if I get something definitive.

Comment: Another option, although this looks abandoned: https://github.com/square1-io/nova-metrics